# Pie chart that successfully works on JR 3.1.4 does not show data in JR 5.0.1

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'm using *iReport* to display a pie chart with 6 different fields. I use *3.1.4* because it is compatible with *Bizflow Advreport*. When previewing the chart in *iReport 3.1.4* the pie chart/legend/titles all show up correctly. But, when I place this on the site it only displays the title. Bringing the file into *5.0.1* nothing shows up, exactly like it does on the website.

I have tried to mess with the margins and the size of the bands, but I cannot seem to get the pie chart to display correctly.

I have also attached the two different previews I receive one from *3.1.4*:

[image: 3.1.4]

and the other from 5.0.1:

[image: 5.0.1]

Also here is the *jrxml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report name" pageWidth="380" pageHeight="300" columnWidth="380" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[Select CapabilityAreaName , SUM(ProjectedDevelopmentCost) as TotalProjectedDevelopmentCost, ROUND(100*SUM(ProjectedDevelopmentCost)/(SELECT SUM(ProjectedDevelopmentCost) FROM RequirementFunding),2)AS percentOfTotal
FROM Requirement
INNER JOIN CapabilityArea
ON Requirement.CapabilityAreaId = CapabilityArea.CapabilityAreaId
INNER JOIN RequirementFunding
ON Requirement.RequirementId = RequirementFunding.RequirementId
GROUP BY CapabilityAreaName]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="CapabilityAreaName" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="TotalProjectedDevelopmentCost" class="java.lang.Double">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="percentOfTotal" class="java.lang.Double">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="50">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="12" width="380" height="25"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Project Development Cost By Capability Area]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="49" width="380" height="1"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="380" height="1"/>
            </line>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="250">
            <pieChart>
                <chart hyperlinkType="Reference">
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="380" height="250"/>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <pieDataset>
                    <keyExpression><![CDATA[$F{CapabilityAreaName}]]></keyExpression>
                    <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{TotalProjectedDevelopmentCost}]]></valueExpression>
                    <labelExpression><![CDATA[$F{percentOfTotal}.toString() + "% - $" + $F{TotalProjectedDevelopmentCost}]]></labelExpression>
                    <sectionHyperlink hyperlinkType="Reference">
                        <hyperlinkReferenceExpression><![CDATA["http://ess-bizflow:8080/bizflowadvreport/flow.html?_flowId=reportTinkerViewReportFlow&reportUnit=/reports/standard_reports/IR_D/AMOD/ActiveRequirementsCostTimeBreakdownTable&&CASelected=" + $F{CapabilityAreaName}]]></hyperlinkReferenceExpression>
                    </sectionHyperlink>
                </pieDataset>
                <piePlot>
                    <plot/>
                </piePlot>
            </pieChart>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
</jasperReport>
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this issue. I can provide files if that is needed as well.

Comment: what jasperreports version do you have on your website? also make sure you have the jars for charts, list the jars you have on the server so we can check..

Comment: The website seems to be running JasperServer Professional 3.1.0.1. I also do not have jars on the website. I have three JRXML files. ActiveRequirementsCostBreakdown.jrxml, ActiveRequirementsCostBreakdown_Subreport1.jrxml, and ActiveRequirementsCostBreakdown_Subreport2.jrxml

Comment: It seems you have put pie chart in column header band, try to put chart in summary band.

Answer (score 2):

It seems from XML you have put pie chart in `<columnhearder>` band try to put the chart in `<summary>` band.

```xml
<columnHeader>
    <band height="250">
        <pieChart>
            <chart hyperlinkType="Reference">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="380" height="250"/>
                <chartTitle/>
                <chartSubtitle/>
                <chartLegend/>
            </chart>
            <pieDataset>
                <keyExpression><![CDATA[$F{CapabilityAreaName}]]></keyExpression>
                <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{TotalProjectedDevelopmentCost}]]></valueExpression>
                <labelExpression><![CDATA[$F{percentOfTotal}.toString() + "% - $" + $F{TotalProjectedDevelopmentCost}]]></labelExpression>
                <sectionHyperlink hyperlinkType="Reference">
                    <hyperlinkReferenceExpression><![CDATA["http://ess-bizflow:8080/bizflowadvreport/flow.html?_flowId=reportTinkerViewReportFlow&reportUnit=/reports/standard_reports/IR_D/AMOD/ActiveRequirementsCostTimeBreakdownTable&&CASelected=" + $F{CapabilityAreaName}]]></hyperlinkReferenceExpression>
                </sectionHyperlink>
            </pieDataset>
            <piePlot>
                <plot/>
            </piePlot>
        </pieChart>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
```

Try this:-

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report name" pageWidth="380" pageHeight="300" columnWidth="380" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[Select CapabilityAreaName , SUM(ProjectedDevelopmentCost) as  
             TotalProjectedDevelopmentCost, 
             ROUND(100*SUM(ProjectedDevelopmentCost)/(SELECT 
        SUM(ProjectedDevelopmentCost) FROM RequirementFunding),2)AS percentOfTotal
      FROM Requirement
      INNER JOIN CapabilityArea
      ON Requirement.CapabilityAreaId = CapabilityArea.CapabilityAreaI d
      INNER JOIN RequirementFunding
      ON Requirement.RequirementId = RequirementFunding.RequirementId
     GROUP BY CapabilityAreaName]]>
</queryString>
<field name="CapabilityAreaName" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="TotalProjectedDevelopmentCost" class="java.lang.Double">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="percentOfTotal" class="java.lang.Double">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<background>
    <band/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="50">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="12" width="380" height="25"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Project Development Cost By Capability Area]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <line>
            <reportElement x="0" y="49" width="380" height="1"/>
        </line>
        <line>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="380" height="1"/>
        </line>
    </band>
</title>
<summary>
    <band height="300">
        <pieChart>
            <chart hyperlinkType="Reference">
                <reportElement x="14" y="15" width="348" height="270"/>
                <chartTitle/>
                <chartSubtitle/>
                <chartLegend/>
            </chart>
            <pieDataset>
                <keyExpression><![CDATA[$F{CapabilityAreaName}]]></keyExpression>
                <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{TotalProjectedDevelopmentCost}]]></valueExpression>
                <labelExpression><![CDATA[$F{percentOfTotal}.toString() + "% - $" + $F{TotalProjectedDevelopmentCost}]]></labelExpression>
                <sectionHyperlink hyperlinkType="Reference">
                    <hyperlinkReferenceExpression><![CDATA["http://ess-bizflow:8080/bizflowadvreport/flow.html?_flowId=reportTinkerViewReportFlow&reportUnit=/reports/standard_reports/IR_D/AMOD/ActiveRequirementsCostTimeBreakdownTable&&CASelected=" + $F{CapabilityAreaName}]]></hyperlinkReferenceExpression>
                </sectionHyperlink>
            </pieDataset>
            <piePlot>
                <plot/>
                <itemLabel/>
            </piePlot>
        </pieChart>
    </band>
</summary>
```

Comment: Hey @Sharad I have tried putting but I now receive an error. Error filling print... null 
java.lang.NullPointerException      at net.sf.jasperreports.charts.fill.JRFillPieDataset.getCustomDataset(JRFillPieDataset.java:256)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillChartDataset.getDataset(JRFillChartDataset.java:55)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillChart$FillChartContext.getDataset(JRFillChart.java:1442)    ......                                          
Print not filled. Try to use an EmptyDataSource...